# Determining input nodes when freezing Tensorflow graphs using tf.data.Datasets

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow `tf.data.Dataset` API as my input pipeline as follows:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((trn_X,trn_y))
train_dataset = 
train_dataset.map(_trn_parse_function,num_parallel_calls=12)
train_dataset = 
train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000).repeat(args.num_epochs)# 
.batch(args.batch_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(args.batch_size))
train_dataset = train_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=600)



val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((val_X,val_y))
val_dataset = val_dataset.map(_val_parse_function,num_parallel_calls=4)
val_dataset = val_dataset.repeat(1)
val_dataset = val_dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.batch_and_drop_remainder(args.batch_size))
val_dataset = val_dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=200)


handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_string_handle(
        handle, train_dataset.output_types, 
train_dataset.output_shapes)

images,labels = iterator.get_next()


train_iter = train_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
val_iter = val_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

Then use this code to switch between training and validation datasets:

```
# Define training and validation handlers
training_handle = sess.run(train_iter.string_handle())
validation_handle = sess.run(val_iter.string_handle())
sess.run(train_iter.initializer)
sess.run(val_iter.initializer)

...
loss = sess.run([train_op],feed_dict={handle:training_handle, 
is_training:True})
```

After training, I save weights, and then freeze the graph from a saved checkpoint((.meta) into the `.pb` format. Subsequently, run the `optimize_for_inference.py` tool provided in the tensorflow repo. This script requires the `input_nodes_names` to be defined. I am unable to determine which is the correct input node for the graph. Here are nodes for my graph:

```
['Variable/initial_value',
'Variable',
'Variable/Assign',
'Variable/read',
'increment_global_step/value',
'increment_global_step',
'Placeholder',
'is_training',
'tensors/component_0',
'tensors/component_1',
'num_parallel_calls',
'batch_size',
'count',
'buffer_size',
'OneShotIterator',
'IteratorToStringHandle',
'IteratorGetNext',
....
....
'output/Softmax]
```

The output nodes can be easily determined, but not the input nodes.

Comment: No, I have tried this. It returns this error:

    ValueError: Input 0 of node import/IteratorFromStringHandle was passed float from import/Placeholder_1:0 incompatible with expected string.

Answer (score 0):

handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[]) is your input, so the tensor is most likely 'Placeholder:0'.

However it would make more sense to write:

```
handle = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[], name="input_placeholder")
```

then you know for sure.